# Using log4net in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, log4net

I figured, that there is a [modified log4net version that supports iOS](https://github.com/drunkirishcoder/monotouch-log4net) and I somewhat see how that was accomplished (it's open source), but unfortunately I don't have enough experience to do that on my own for Android.

I tried my best and got the ConsoleAppender to work on Android, but the FileAppender seems to need mutexes and they are not supported on Android as far as I understand.

So is there any way I can get log4net to work on Android?

Comment: Were you about to a proper solution for this. Ran across these 2 links on Log4Net's bug site (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-435) and (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-549)

Comment: That's exactly how I managed to do it a few months ago